# Regular expression searching special tag

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I have a special tag in text `[Attachment: image;upload;url]` to parse it I need to find all this tags, I have wrote this regular expression:
`preg_match_all("/.*(\[Attachment: (.*);upload;(.*)\]).*/", $text, $matches);`

All work fine, it returns this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            Text
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Attachment: image;upload;url]
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            image
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            url
        )

)
```

But here is one problem, when text contains two or more tags, it will return info only about last founded tag.

Comment: Can we have example input and example outputs, please?

Comment: Yes, Array[0] it's input data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should match only the tags, not the surrounding text:

```
"/\[Attachment: ([^;]*);upload;([^\]]*)\]/"
```

Instead of the negative character set you could also use `.*?` to use non-greedy matching; however, I prefer to use the look-ahead set.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `.*` part from the end of the regex. With the `.*`, the regex matches to the end of the string, including any of the other substrings that you want to find. (Or at least all the ones on the same line - I can't remember what the default settings are in PHP.) After that it looks for more matches from the end of the string, but can't find any.

Comment: It don't work correctly, then it will return a not clean result and it can contain html code or other text for example.

Comment: What Jack said. I guess the moral is that greedy all-characters matches (`.*`) are a bad idea. I removed the one at the end but forgot the ones in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

This regex should do it:

> $regex = '/[Attachment: (.*?);(.*?);(.*?)]/';
>
> preg_match_all($regex, $string, $matches);

For me, this came back with what you wanted (3 results);